# Knitr PDF ok, but no content and error messages

Tags: r, knitr

Appologies from the go, still getting my head around all the functions in R and RStudio, so some of you might think I'm a total idiot for asking this. BTW: I've translated some of the stuff produced by R from German to english.

I'm running RStudio Version 0.97.551 on a MAC OS X, Version 10.8.5.

I'm trying to compile a PDF using knitr. I installed knitr, ran it by using library() and set my working directory to the same directory as my default working directory, which is also the same folder that contains the .txt files I use as my datasets. And have chosen knitr as the default for weaving Rnw files.
I then installed MacTex basic from http://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html to use for my LaTex which is a subset from TeXLive (2013).

So far so good.

I then open a new Sweave file, RStudio has recognized that I'm using some form of TeX program and then plug in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{My first Knitr Output File}
\author{Oliver M. Fisher, MD}
\maketitle{BMI Category Crosstabulation}
<<>>=
attach(MIC1ELISANEW)
tab1=table(BMICat, Diagnosis)
tab1
summary(tab1)
@

<<>>=
tab1=table(MIC1ELISANEW$BMICat, MIC1ELISANEW$Diagnosis)
summary(tab1)
@

\end{document}
```

Hit "compile PDF" which gives me this log

```
grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE); require(knitr); opts_knit$set(concordance =TRUE);     knit('Example.Rnw')
Opening packet: knitr
Warning:
Packet ‘knitr’ was developed under R Version 3.0.2


processing file: Example.Rnw
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
  label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
  label: unnamed-chunk-2
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: Example.tex

[1] "Example.tex"
> 
> 
Running pdflatex on Example.tex...completed

Created PDF: ~/Documents/Australia/AMR : Gastro/Papers/Oliver/MIC1/Datasets/ELISA/Example.pdf
```

And opens a PDF, that looks the following ("nicht gefunden" means "not found" in English):

My first Knitr Output File

Oliver M. Fisher, MD February 3, 2014

BMI Category Crosstabulation

attach(MIC1ELISANEW)

```
Error:  Objekt ’MIC1ELISANEW’ nicht gefunden
```

tab1 = table(BMICat, Diagnosis)

```
Error:  Objekt ’BMICat’ nicht gefunden
```

tab1

```
Error:  Objekt ’tab1’ nicht gefunden
```

summary(tab1)

```
Error:  Objekt ’tab1’ nicht gefunden
```

tab1 = table(MIC1ELISANEW$BMICat, MIC1ELISANEW$Diagnosis)

```
Error:  Objekt ’MIC1ELISANEW’ nicht gefunden
```

summary(tab1)

```
Error:  Objekt ’tab1’ nicht gefunden
```

I've tried inputing the R code by either a) copy&pasting it from an R script file, copy&pasting it from the RStudio console and also sending it to the "source" by clicking on that icon in the RStudio history window. Nothing works. 
If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,

Oliver

P.S. I tried posting a picture, but don't have enough reputation to do so.....

Answer (score 3):

Using the `compilePDF` button runs a script using `Rscript` and does not work in the global environment you see in `Rstudio`.

As such, your script does not read in or load `MIC1ELISANEW`, hence the errors.

---

Update.

One of the main purposes of `knitr` is *reproducible* data analysis, as such it is sensible that a `.Rnw` file, or a collection thereof contain all the information to reproduce the report / analysis.

Therefore your `.Rnw` file should create all objects required.

Simply add the required code. eg:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{My first Knitr Output File}
\author{Oliver M. Fisher, MD}
\maketitle{BMI Category Crosstabulation}

<<>>=
# load the required data
MIC1ELISANEW <- read.table('relativepathtofile')
@

<<>>=
attach(MIC1ELISANEW)
tab1=table(BMICat, Diagnosis)
tab1
summary(tab1)
@

<<>>=
tab1=table(MIC1ELISANEW$BMICat, MIC1ELISANEW$Diagnosis)
summary(tab1)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you mean, that besides saving a new *.Rnw file I should also save a new *.R file, which contains all of the script, I'll be putting into the *.Rnw file? BTW: A semi-working solution was by first adding the chunk load(".RData"), then read.table("MIC1ELISANEW.txt", header=TRUE), which made it at least be able to access the data included in the *.txt file. But I've tried working on other data now and I'm back to square one.............

Comment: @OFish - see my edit. A fully reproducible document is what you want, i.e. load all external data explicitly.

Comment: Ah thanks man! What I found out you have to do first though, is add the code read.delim(relativepathtofile) before adding the read.table() code. Now to bother you with one last thing, any idea, why when I include <<include=FALSE>>= as a tex argument prior to the chunk, the pdf won't compile? I get the following erorr message:

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, 

Any idea why? I also if I add <<error=FALSE>>= I get the same issue, the PDF compilation stops with the same message......

Thanks mate!

Comment: Ofish - Edit your question and make the question reproducible.

Comment: the tex code that causes the compilation of the PDF to stop is simple:

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{MIC-1 Uni- and multivariable analysis}
\author{Oliver M. Fisher, MD}
\maketitle

<<error=FALSE>>=
ELISAPathComparison_3 <- read.delim("~/Documents/Australia/AMR : Gastro/Papers/Oliver/MIC1/Datasets/ELISA/ELISAPathComparison_3.txt")
ELISAPathComparison_3<-read.table("~/Documents/Australia/AMR : Gastro/Papers/Oliver/MIC1/Datasets/ELISA/ELISAPathComparison_3.txt", header=TRUE)
@